# Can Apache Shiro be used for Android Studio Applications?

Tags: java, android, shiro, android-security, java-security

I am currently building an android application for my final year degree project but at the moment I have very basic login functionality.

At the moment it is just a username and password stored in a MySQL server, the program fires off a request which runs some PHP to check to see if the username exists in the table and the password is correct. This won't be anywhere near secure enough, I just wanted a placeholder while I got on with other parts of the app.

I've been looking at existing frameworks which can provide secure authentication/authorization as well as session management so the user doesn't have to constantly log on whenever they re-open the app. Apache Shiro (https://shiro.apache.org/) sounds like a potential solution but I've had a good search on Google but haven't found any examples in which it is used for Android projects.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use it for Android Apps? Or if there are any decent alternatives?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

A security service is deployed in a "remote" machine (the server). Your Android app (the client), when a user tries to login, sends a POST to a "/login" endpoint exposed by the server. If successful it will reply with a cookie that the client will use in the further request to identify its session. It is not difficult with a maven project Spring and Shiro libraries, but you need to implement at least a simple WebApp (expose /login, use shiro to verify the credential) deployed in a separate server. If you are ready to write two java app Shiro is a good choice.